# Is there any consideration of the intermolecular forces in a plasma?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, plasma-physics

It seems like generally people use the following argument to ignore this: that in many case that we have created them, plasmas are low density.  Therefore we can ignore their intermolecular forces as a first approximation.

So here's my general question:  is that just a deflection to avoid talking about the permanent electric dipole moment of the electron?  And, given that the general conclusion there is "the electric dipole moment is very small, if not zero", why isn't the very next step in the discussion consideration of induced dipoles in higher density plasmas?  We know the polarizability is non-zero, where's that next approximation?

Am I just missing these reviews and references or do they have some insider lingo?  Have been trying for a bit now to answer myself, apologies if this is a dumb question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So here's my general question: is that just a deflection to avoid talking about the permanent electric dipole moment of the electron? And, given that the general conclusion there is "the electric dipole moment is very small, if not zero", why isn't the very next step in the discussion consideration of induced dipoles in higher density plasmas? We know the polarizability is non-zero, where's that next approximation?

I am not sure I understand your question but a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) is a kinetic gas governed by long-range forces (i.e., electromagnetic) that exhibits a collective behavior because of these long-range forces.  Plasmas are also *quasi-neutral*, which means that the number of positive charges balances the negatives so that outside a [Debye sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length) the electric fields are shielded from those within.

Plasmas do have finite susceptibilities (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/547993/59023) and their [index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) is not that of vacuum.  In fact, the index of refraction for a plasma can get very complicated even for simple systems.

So to answer your question as to why we don't worry too much about each electron's dipole moment in a plasma, it's because the Coulomb potentials are dominating their dynamics.  In extreme environments like near a [pulsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar) or [magnetar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar), the spin of the electrons and positrons actually do matter.  In fact, the spin of fermions can matter greatly in relativistic plasmas under certain conditions (e.g., see discussion in answers to this question [What is the correct relativistic distribution function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216819/59023)).

> Is there any consideration of the intermolecular forces in a plasma?

Generally no because the dynamics are controlled by (and well predicted by) long-range electromagnetic forces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132421/discussion-on-answer-by-honeste-vivere-is-there-any-consideration-of-the-intermo).